# SSL on a Parse Server

Tags: node.js, ssl, parse-server

I have a production mobile app running on Parse Server, hosted on DigitalOcean. This is my setup:

```
Droplet no1: Parse Server and Dashboard
Droplet no2: MongoDB
```

And this is how the client connects to the Parse Server:

```
let productionServerConfiguration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "applicationId"
    $0.clientKey = "clientKey"
    $0.server = "http://domain:1337/parse"
}
```

Now I want to add an SSL certificate to the Parse Server, but I'm afraid of what will happen to the existing users, that still have `http`. Also, do I need to add an SSL certificate to the MongoDB Server?

Comment: You will have to deploy a new version of your app in which it will connect using https instead of http. You can also create a secure communication between Parse Server and MongoDB but it is an independent task.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Yeah but what will happen to those users who are still on a previous version and still use http?

Comment: Depends on how you will setup the server. If you setup it to only allow https, Your users will receive error until they update their apps. What you can do is actually setup the server to accept both http and https, update the app, wait for the users to update their apps, and then change the server to only accept https.

Comment: And how can I make it accept both http and https? By using nginx?

Comment: It really depends on your server setup and where you are hosting, but, yes, it can be achieve with nginx for example.